# Issue with implementing horizontal group menu in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs and was implementing a menu framework which would be both vertical & horizontal depending on a button toggle.The menu being implemented is with custom directives which looks like below.

```
<my-menu>
    <my-menu-item></my-menu-item>
    <my-menu-group label="Fruits">
        <my-menu-item label="Apple"></my-menu-item>
        <my-menu-item label="Orange"></my-menu-item>
    </my-menu-group>
    <my-menu-group label="Vegetables">
        <my-menu-item label="Tomato"></my-menu-item>
        <my-menu-item label="Beans"></my-menu-item>
    </my-menu-group>
<my-menu>
```

The template for the `<my-menu-group>` is:

```
<li class="my-selectable-item" ng-click="clickedMenuGroupItem()" ng-class="{'my-item-horizontal': !isVertical()}">
<div class="acc-noselect">
    <i class="fa {{icon}} my-menu-icon"></i>
    {{label}}
    <i ng-if="isVertical()"
       class="fa fa-angle-right my-group-indicator-left" ng-class="{'fa-rotate-90':isOpen}"></i>

    <i ng-if="!isVertical()" style="margin-left:5px;"
       class="fa fa-angle-down" ng-class="{'fa-rotate-180':isOpen}"></i>

</div>
```

The link function has the code snippet as :

```
link: function(scope,el,attr,ctrl) {
            scope.isOpen = false;
            scope.closeMenu = function () {
                scope.isOpen = false;
            };
            scope.clickedMenuGroupItem = function () {
                scope.isOpen = !scope.isOpen;
                if (el.parents('.my-subitem-section').length === 0) 
                    scope.setSubmenuPosition();
                ctrl.setOpenMenuScope(scope);
            };

            scope.isVertical = function() {
                return ctrl.isVertical() || el.parents('.my-subitem-section').length > 0;
            };

            scope.setSubmenuPosition = function(){
                var pos = el.offset();
                $('.my-subitem-section').css({'left':pos.left + 20, 'top' : 40});
            };
        }
```

Vertical menu works just fine.However when the menu is horizontal if I click on 'Fruits' I get the respective list values and then when i click on vegetables both the list gets rendered.What I'm expecting is a toggle functionality.The bottom line here is that I m not able to control the scope of previously clicked element in the link function.
I've tried my best to be as descriptive as possible here.Please help ?